# JOptionPane.showInputDialog issue

Tags: java, string, null

I might just be tired. But no matter what I've tried the code always executes.
How can I get the code below to only execute if the String contains characters?

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter your budget!", "Set Budget", 1);

    //If the input isnt empty
    System.out.println(input);
    if(!"".equals(input) || input != null){
        try{
            budgetValue = Double.parseDouble(input);
            budgetIn.setText(String.format("$%1$,.2f", budgetValue));
                setDifference();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable to set budget!\n" +
                                                "Please enter a usable value!", "Sorry!", 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use AND(&&) operator instead of OR(||) in `if` conditional.

Comment: ALSO: that system.out.println() is for me to see that the string in indeed null

Comment: Oh man. Thanks.. Ive been programming in Java for a while, and never ran into that issue with ||.. Can you explain why please?

Comment: As long as your input is not null, the `OR` condition will return `true`.

Comment: Oh. Haha! I didn't think of it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider trying something like...

```
if(input != null && !input.trim().isEmpty()){...}
```

This should ensure that the `if` statement is executed so long as the content is not empty

Beware though, this trims the `input` of white spaces, so if you just type spaces and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will skip over the `if` statement ;)

**Updated**

To filter the `input` `String` to ensure it only contains valid numerical values, you could use [`String#match`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) and a regular expression...

```
if (input != null && input.matches("^\\d+(\\.(\\d+)?)?$")) {...}
```

This should ensure that the `if` statement is only executed when you enter numerical values.  The decimals (decimal place) is optional

Comment: Thanks! Regardless, it throws an exception if the user inputs something other than a double.

Comment: I thought you wanted the `if` statement to executed if the user entered *"if the String contains characters?"* ;)